# Inhibiting I/O responses to OS

Tags: c++, windows, io

So a little backstory is that I have a mouse (deathadder) that is glitching out, and will sometimes register a single click as two clicks.  Without explanation.  It is apparent that this is quite annoying.

The goal is to perform some tests to figure out how fast these mouse clicks are being registered between each other.  For example, after clicking once, the second automatically gets registered within .001 nanoseconds.  Once I get this value, I plan to inhibit the OS from registering any mouse clicks during this time but I am not exactly sure on how I can inhibit I/Os to the OS.

Observing clicks is easy to determine but how do I prevent a button/mouse click from being registered for the Windows OS?

Comment: Do you really believe that there's only one operating system in existence, or that every operating system used in the world handles mouse event processes in exactly the same way, so that a single answer will apply to every computer in existence?

Comment: Sorry meant to specify that I am aiming at Windows

Comment: Not what you asked for, but have you thought about repairing the mouse instead? Usually the problem is a semi-broken button inside, which you can easily replace with a new one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I was thinking of trying to fix it programming first, if that doesnt work out, I'll try my hand at fixing it manually or just buying a new mouse

Comment: I seem to recall a similar question being asked in MSDN magazine back in 1994 or 1995.  If you have access to the MSDN magazine library, maybe you can find it there.

Comment: There seems to be an AutoHotKey solution, if that would work for you: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/34911-stop-double-click-if-too-fast/

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I'll have to try this out when I get home but it looks promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you would need to implement this as an upper filter driver. It is a pretty complex and treacherous process, and I would only recommend it if you were doing it out of sheer curiosity. As @HolyBlackCat says, fixing the mouse or buying a new one are the sensible options. But then, what would life be without whimsy?

Here's a couple of links to get you started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128324(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction! Although it'll be quit the task, who doesn't enjoy a good challenge?